# How to query for all posts within custom WordPress categories

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress database that I need to query with pure MySQL to select all posts from a custom taxonomy called 'guide_category'. I also want to order the results by the `wp_terms.name` and within those order by `wp_posts.name`. A post can reside within multiple categories.

So results should looks something like:

```
Category_A
    Post A
    Post B
    Post C
Category_B
    Post A
    Post B
    Post C
Category_C
    Post A
    Post B
    Post C
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of the tables?

Comment: ***WHY*** SQL and not native Wordpress

Comment: There are a ton of reasons to use SQL and not wordpress. Perhaps it is a different technology that is looking to use wordpress data, perhaps it is for migration purposes, yadda yadda.

Comment: @AdamErstelle I think Pieter question is valid.  Depending on the answer a different solution might be given such as using WP_query to write JSON object that can be accessed by a mobile app. Even a plugin can be offered as a solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
SELECT name, post_title
FROM wp_term_taxonomy AS cat_term_taxonomy
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS cat_terms ON cat_term_taxonomy.term_id = cat_terms.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS cat_term_relationships ON cat_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = cat_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts AS cat_posts ON cat_term_relationships.object_id = cat_posts.ID
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta ON cat_posts.ID = meta.post_id
WHERE cat_posts.post_status =  'publish'
AND cat_term_taxonomy.taxonomy =  'guide_category'
GROUP BY name, post_title
ORDER BY name, post_title
```

Answer (score 8):

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 1
ORDER BY post_date DESC
";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

replace  term_taxonomy.term_id = 1 with your texonomy id 
may it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

In looking at the WP_Tax_Query class in /wp-includes/taxonomy.php, I found that there is a 'include_children' option which defaults to true. I modified my original get_posts() call with the following, and it works great:

```
$pages = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'post'
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name'
    )
  )
));
```

List of more query parameters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: I'm looking for a pure MySQL answer...not PHP/WordPress.